# 502 error ubuntu 14.04, Nginx, uWSGI, python3, and django

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, uwsgi

I'm trying to get a site up on a digital ocean droplet, running ubuntu 14.04. For some reason though I keep getting 502 errors. It will work seemingly fine for a little bit, and then out of no where I get a 502 error. If I restart uwsgi it seems to solve it, but only temporarily.

Here's my /etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid adam
setgid www-data

exec /home/adam/Env/itinerary/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

Here's my /etc/uwsgi/sites/itinerary.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
project = itinerary
base = /home/adam

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket =  %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacumm = true
```

Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/itinerary file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/adam/itinerary;
        }

        location / {
                include         uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/adam/itinerary/itinerary.sock;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `uwsgi` put any errors in its logfile?

Comment: What's the file path to the logfile? I'm looking in /var/log/ directory and don't see anything that seems to be uwsgi related.

Comment: In the nginx error log it simply  return a 111 connection refused error

Comment: I don't know `uwsgi`. But connection refused means that `uwsgi` no longer runs. So have to find out why it has stopped.

Comment: Thank you I managed to figure it out, I was trying to running through the virutalenv and instead I had to install it globally and run it there. I'm not really sure why it worked but it did.